# Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?

Tags: c++, ide

I'm using the `<XZY>` IDE to compile my program, and have some trouble to import/integrate a specific library with it.

I get error messages like

```
fatal error: 3rdPartyLib.h: No such file or directory
```

for a

```
#include "3rdPartyLib.h"
```

statement

```
ld.exe: cannot find `lib3rdParty.a`
```

for specifying

```
3rdParty
```

in the additional libraries

At least I got some error message like

```
undefined reference to `lib3rdParty::foo()'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a common misconception, that the current IDE used, is responsible for getting errors like stated in the question.
See for example

- [c++ lib in two same project ,one can work but the other can 't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714239/c-lib-in-two-same-project-one-can-work-but-the-other-can-t/24714445#24714445)
- [Issue linking libxml++ and glib libraries with CodeBlocks IDE for C++ Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642238/issue-linking-libxml-and-glib-libraries-with-codeblocks-ide-for-c-windows)
- ...

The problem is almost never related to the currently used IDE.
In the most cases the solution boils down, to supply the actual toolchain's compiler/linker with the appropriate path's to search for included headers, to be linked libraries.

One of the major applicable answers for the linker related problems are

> - **[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)**
> - **[undefined reference to `WinMain@16'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)**

---

Most of the common IDEs provide features to configure this for a specific project. Here are some samples

---

**Eclipse-CDT**

Include path settings:
[image]

Library & library search path settings
[image]

---

**Visual Studio 2013**

[image]

---

**Code Blocks**
[image]
[image]

---

**DEV C++ (Bloodshed C++)

As from their FAQ:

> **9. How can i use the OpenGL library and others ?**
>
> All the libraries that comes with Mingw reside in the Lib directory. They are all named in the following way: `lib*.a`
>   To link a library with your project, just add in Project options, Further option files :
>   `-lopengl32`
>   This is for including the `libopengl32.a` library. To add any other library, just follow the same syntax: 
>   Type `-l` (L in lowercase) plus the base name of the library (filename without `lib` and the `.a` extension).

You may also consider putting a `-L` option there to add directory pathes searched for libraries.

---

**Qt Creator**

In order to add include paths you have to open up the .pro file and then add
the directories to the `INCLUDEPATH` variable. These paths are separated by spaces. Reference can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath).

[image: Showing INCLUDEPATH]

---

If none of the above samples applies for your actually used IDE/toolchain, I hope you're able to get the point of abstraction:

> **It's an issue how to provide compiling/linking options to your actual toolchain. The IDE used to setup the context is a minor point here.**

Answer (score 2):

For **eclipse** I use the `pkg-config` plugin where possible:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt

Failing that this configuration window:

[image]