# Setting default VC++ Directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, directx

I recently installed VS 2013 Express for Windows. But when debugging a sample VC++ DirectX (Universal) app i get nearly 220 errors. I think  the problem is at Visual C++ directories that i manually have changed to Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)  on VS 2012, but those changes are automatically applied to VS 2013 installation. I exactly have modified Executable,include and library directories. I want to know how to set those directories on default state again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: *I exactly have modified Executable,include and library directories* there's almost never a good reason for that. Add the correct include and library paths to your project instead. *but those changes are automatically applied to VS 2013 installation* are you sure?? VC++ directories in VS2013 are settings local to the project. See Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ directories

Comment: yes i am sure, the same changes that i made to VS 2012 , were applied to VS 2013 after i installed it, so VC++ directories have the same paths  on both VS 2012 and 2013.