# How to set the '-l' argument for g++ in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Trying to compile a boost C++ code I have found out that one needs to name the libraries to be used explicit. So, given the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

namespace bfs=boost::filesystem;
int main()
{
    bfs::path p("second.cpp");
    if(bfs::exists(p))
    std::cout<<p.leaf()<<std::endl;
}
```

I am able to compile (and link) it with the following command line

```
g++   -o main main.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

How can I define those `-l` libraries in **eclipse**, so that eclipse is able to compile (and link) the code without an `undefined reference` error?

This is a question on the usage and configuration of **eclipse**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because the question you link to is in no way related to eclipse. My question is an exclusive eclipse question, I am not asking a question about the 'undefined reference' error. Please read question carefully next time.

Comment: Your question is answered there for Eclipse as well as for some other IDEs. Or isn't it?

Comment: I see there are many ways to set the libraries. Well, I guess your link might answer it, although it does not mention explicitly to set the used libraries in one of the windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to

```
Project -> Properties
```

and then add the libraries you want to use manually. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So what is this C/C++ General section for then? I tried this solution and it works. So why is this wrong?

Comment: Seems to work equally, though I never used these settings to setup build configurations, just to make stuff available for the indexer.