# Error - installation of SDL2 in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, window, sdl-2

Currently I'm trying to install the last version of SDL, and I'm trying to link Eclipse,SDL and MingWG.

But after lots of tries, I got an error.

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDLmain
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So I guess Eclipse cann't find the SDL_main.h.

But I have specified MingWG,SDLmain,SDL2 in librairy, so I don't really understand how can I fix the problem.

Thank you in advance. All idea is welcome. If you need more information, ask me.

Answer (score 0):

> *"So I guess Eclipse cann't find the SDL_main.h."*

No, that's a linker error. You probably missed to specify the path where the linker should lookup the libraries. The `-L` option is supposed to do this (check the Eclipse c++-Build options please).

Here's some more information: [Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this)