# codeBlocks cannot find -lwxmsw29u

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I wanted to set up wxWidgets with CodeBlocks do did everything like in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuPiZ86EFhQ
But when I'm trying to run program, I got an error:
"cannot find -lwxmsw29u"
I don't know what to do with this, so I'm asking for help.

Comment: maybe your codeblocks compiler/ide is broken

Comment: or maybe *Install wxWidgets to a directory without whitespace in the path name! Otherwise this will cause trouble*

Comment: When I run other programs (without wxWidgets) CB works fine.
My wx path is: C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\

Comment: See the problem might be that the tutorial was for " wxWidgets(2.9.4)" but you got wxWidgets-3.0.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: Comment from @Bot should be the answer: obviously you need to use the correct (i.e. `wxmsw30u`) library name.