# How to copy linked libraries from a code::blocks project to another one?

Tags: c++, linker, project, libraries, portaudio

I recently began working with the PortAudio library for C++. To compile even the simplest example I have to link my project to 8 different libraries. I am working with code::blocks as an IDE. I would like to create a new project and tell the linker to link to the same 8 libraries so I don't have to enter them manually for each new project. Can this be done?

Comment: May be this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this

Comment: That's interesting but I already know how to link all the libraries to compile successfully. What I want to know is if I can export my library setup to a new project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to what [Mike Kinghan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529767/5456600), the feature you're looking for exists, and is called Project Templates.

Set up a project's compiler and build options (search and linker tabs, etc.), and save the project as a template from the file menu. It will show up under User Templates in the new project menu, and create a project setup just like the one the template was saved from.

Optionally, you can save the template with files you'd like included, and it will save a copy of those files to the template as well, and include them with each new project created by that template.

No need to setup a bunch of new compiler entries, that's not what it's for.

See [the Code::Blocks docs page](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-50001.3).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a Code::Blocks feature that would let you
create a new project "based" on a previous one, meaning that all of
the toolchain options would be copied from the previous project.

That would be nice, but it doesn't exist.

There's a reasonably painless workaround, however, thanks to the fact that
C::B does allow you to define a new *toolchain*, based on an existing one.

You want to develop numeruous projects all around the PortAudio library. So,
in the C::B IDE:

- From the menu-bar, navigate **Settings** -> **Compiler**
- You see the **Selected Compiler**. It's probably the one you want for
  your PortAudio work, and let's say it's `GNU GCC Compiler 4.8`. If the
  selected compiler happens *not* to be the one you want, then use the dropdown
  menu to select the one you do want.
- Underneath the selected compiler, click the **Copy** button. You are
  prompted to **Add a new compiler**, and to enter the new compiler's name.
  Call it, say, `GCC 4.8 for PortAudio`, and click `OK`.
- Next, you are prompted to *update the toolchain executables page*. Again click OK.
- Now you see that the selected compiler is your new one, `GCC 4.8 for PortAudio`,
  and all of its settings are at your disposal. Right now, they are all exactly
  the same as for GCC 4.8.
- Do *not* update the **Toolchain executables**, because you want to use the GCC 4.8
  toolchain unchanged. But you *do* want to change the **Linker settings** (
  and maybe the **Search directories**, maybe the **Compiler settings**.) Set up
  the **Linker settings** (etc.) just the way you have done in the PortAudio
  project(s) that you have already successfully configured, and save them.

Now, `GCC 4.8 for PortAudio` is a "virtual toolchain" that is basically
GCC 4.8, but customized for PortAudio projects. When you want to create
a new PortAudio project without re-entering all the common settings,
just choose `GCC 4.8 for PortAudio` as the project's compiler when you're
going through the project creation wizard, or else select it as the project's
compiler from the project's **Build options** after you have created it.

Comment: Thank you! Such a great answer. I just had the time to test this and it works nicely. It is basically what I want. Although it is not a 1-click solution, it is pretty straight forward and get the job done. Awesome!