# Using DllImport in DEV C ++

Tags: c++, c, dllimport, dev-c++

Good day,

I have a problem when trying to use an external library,

I have 3 files provided by the manufacturer.

`Fwlib32.dll` -> Functions and Structs

`Fwlib32.h` -> External Statements

`Fwlib32.lib` -> I do not know what does this hehhehe

```
#include "fwlib32.h"

int main()
{
    unsigned short h;
    cnc_allclibhndl3("192.168.200.1", 8193, 10, &h );
    //cnc_resetconnect(&h);
    return 1;
}
```

When compiling displays the following error: `undefined reference to '_imp__cnc_allclibhndl3@16'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to put `Fwlib32.lib` to the additional libraries linked to your DEV C++ project. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this) also, I'm pretty sure DEV C++ provides a similar project configuration option.

Comment: I created a project and went in the project options -> Parameters -> Linker -> and selected the .lib file and it worked thank you. :)