# Add C++ Library to eclipse C++ Project

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, eclipse-cdt

I am attempting to add an existing library to Eclipse. I use a [cross compiler](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/) for C++ with the Eclipse IDE, installed on a virtual linux debian machine.

The `mmapGpio` lib is found [here](http://hertaville.com/OTHERFILES).

`/mmapGpioBasicRev1.tar.gz` has a `cpp` and an `h` file with a small demo program.

I have compiled this code without a problem. A `.o` file is generated. I've archived the file successfully with `ar -q libmmapGpio.a mmapgpio.o`

I've placed my `libmmapGpio.a` in `~/.../UserLib directory`
I've placed my `mmapGpio.h` in `~/.../UserInclude`

At this point all is OK.

I open a new project that uses the `mmapGpio` library:

```
#include "mmapGpio.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void){
    mmapGpio rpiGpio; // instantiate an instance of the mmapGpio class
    rpiGpio.setPinDir(17,mmapGpio::OUTPUT); // set GPIO17 to output
    while(1) {// toggle pin as fast as possible
           rpiGpio.writePinHigh(17);
           rpiGpio.writePinLow(17); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So cross-compilation is done, but linker say `cannot find -llibmapGpio`!

I have made declaration in the properties project; C/C++ General

- includes path : `/home/octopuss/rpi/UserInclude` (the mmapGpio.h file)
- Library path  : `/home/octopuss/rpi/UserLib` (the libmmapGpio.a file)
- Libraries     : `libmmapGpio`

Why do I receive this message?

for detail -> console view

```
03:16:30 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Gpio1 ****
make all 
Building file: ../Gpio1.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -I/home/octopuss/rpi/UserInclude -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Gpio1.d" -MT"Gpio1.d" -o "Gpio1.o" "../Gpio1.cpp"
Finished building: ../Gpio1.cpp

Building target: Gpio1
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L/home/octopuss/rpi/UserLib -o "Gpio1"  ./Gpio1.o   -lmmapGpio
/home/octopuss/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/octopuss/rpi/UserLib/libmmapGpio.so when searching for -lmmapGpio
/home/octopuss/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmapGpio
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Gpio1] Erreur 1
```

error :

- skipping incompatible /home/.../UserLib/libmmapGpio.so when searching for -lmmapGpio
- ld: cannot find -lmmapGpio

Comment: I suggest you do this from the command line outside eclipse - once you understand the steps and have it cross compiling correctly then for future productivity setup eclipse

Comment: thank you for your answer Scott: to compile any problems, but it comes to cross compile for ARM linux system (gcc_linaro) on the command line when looking at the Eclipse console it's been very very long commands. I tried to put pictures of the console but I'm too new to the forum I renounce the photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"why this message ?"*

It's because with your settings, the linker actually looks up for a library file named `liblibmmapGpio.a`.

> *"... so crosscompilation is done but linker say "cannot find -llibmapGpio" !
>
>   ...
>
>    - Libraries : libmmapGpio"*

You just need to specify the library without the `lib` prefix in the linker library settings:

`mmapGpio`

[image]

The Eclipse CDT Builder passes this as a `-l` option to the linker, which automatically extends to search for **`libmmapGpio.a`** at the specified additional pathes.

See also this Q&A for more illustrated samples and links:
[Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: I'have try to use shared library : limmapGpio.so ... Result is same :

Comment: @BernardMASTROGIACOMO Shared libraries provide a corresponding stub file. Naming convention regarding `-l` stay the same, without the `lib` prefix, without any file extension.

Comment: I have completed question see console log lib is well declared but "incompatible" ?

Comment: finally about many forum he seems to be an error to my system in 64 bit ? I could install ia32 lib .

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem ... my .so lib wasn't ARM cross compiled so there is a X86 library not compatible whith my ARM Programm.

I solve this to set erm-linuxgnuabihf- prefix and his path to cross setting parameter.

Thanks to TTAVAR PEI and Scott Stensland

enjoy