# CodeBlocks - "undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection' "

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks

Trying to build a project I get the error: "undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection' ". I did a research and found that i should link to `libX11.so`.

I did add in CodeBlocks under `Compiler Settings->Linker Settings->Add` the directory `"/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so"`. However, error remains.

System: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Code::Blocks v.13.12

32 bit

I spent hours with google, still could not find a working solution. Thanks for your help!

The proposed solution linked, states:

> "In the most cases the solution boils down, to supply the actual toolchain's compiler/linker with the appropriate path's to search for included headers, to be linked libraries."

That is exactly what i did (at least i think i did). However, it does not fix the error.

Comment: `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so` How is this a _directory_ actually? Please read that Q&A and the given links thoroughly! You don't ever link against a `.so` file directly, but use an appropriate stub lib (`.a`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I did add in CodeBlocks under `Compiler Settings->Linker Settings->Add` the directory `"/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so"`. However, error remains."*

`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so` isn't a directory. You want to specify the link library path to `-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and link against `X11` using the `-lX11` option.

To add a search path for the linker use that `Search Directories` tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I put the -lX11 option under "other linker options". Where do I specify the link library path? If I browse under "link libraries", I am asked for (*.a, *.so, *.lib, *.dylib, *.bundle)

Comment: @NoMorePen As mentioned in my [answer to that duplicate I've linked before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24715865/1413395) you provide it at the _`Search Directories->Linker`_ tab. I'll replicate that screenshot in my answer here.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but it did not work, error remains. I checked everything twice. Any other suggestions?