# Makefiles, How do I access them?

Tags: c++, makefile, codeblocks

In another question someone asked to post makefiles. Where would these be located? Or how can I find my makefiles so I can post them?

Comment: make files would be given the extension ".mak" so you can use find command to find all the files ending with *.mak in your project

Comment: @Ram A large number don't even have an extension so it's kind of pointless to search for `*.mak`

Comment: @Ram: I have never seen a make file with _any_ extension. I'm not saying they don't exist, but they are likely to be the exception rather than the rule. Make files are usually called `Makefile`.

Comment: May be [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this). Your IDE probably generates the `Makefile`'s in question automatically.

Comment: This currently has close votes, but the reason is bogus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wrote them, you know where they are. You put them in that place and have a built-in memory.

If you did not write any, then you cannot provide them.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, you may be able to have the IDE publish or generate the makefile.