# Undefined reference to sample void function

Tags: c++

well I want to understand linking with headers and other .cpp (functions for example) so my quastion is why I get "undefined reference to 'afis(). There are sample example and I want to clarify this. Also sorry for my bad english :D.

There is main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    afis();
    return 0;
}
```

There is an function named function.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void afis(){
    cout <<"yehe";
}
```

And there is the header :

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

void afis();

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Please include the commands you are using to compile your code.

Answer (score 2):

While the C++ compiler automatically "pulls in" referenced header files, it can't do that for the actual `.cpp` code files.

Instead of calling

`CXX/clang++/g++ main.cpp -o hello`

you need to manually include all relevant code files:

`CXX/clang++/g++ main.cpp functions.cpp -o hello`

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, where to include this line, I'm using Codeblocks and I don't have "make files" file .

Comment: @zVoxty You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this) helpful. Just assure that `functions.cpp` is part of your codeblocks project.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for stepping in. I probably haven't touched CodeBlocks since 2006!