# How to read a pcap file from wireshark with visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

I need to set up a programming environment to read pcap files from Wireshark.(C++)
Software libraries to read pcap files.(I do not know)
I also need a DNS message parser to get the contents of the DNS
messages.(also I did not find)

This what I did:
I captured a traffic using Wireshark and save the file. 
I followed this steps from this site ((https://www.rhyous.com/2011/11/13/how-to-read-a-pcap-file-from-wireshark-with-c/))
This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcap.h>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
string file = "C:\\Users\\It-am\\Desktop\\Master\\dns-ipv4-ipv6.pcap";

char errbuff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

pcap_t * pcap = pcap_open_offline(file.c_str(), errbuff);

struct pcap_pkthdr *header;

const u_char *data;

u_int packetCount = 0;

while (int returnValue = pcap_next_ex(pcap, &header, &data) >= 0)
{
    printf("Packet # %i\n", ++packetCount);
    printf("Packet size: %d bytes\n", header->len);

    if (header->len != header->caplen)
        printf("Warning! Capture size different than packet size: %ld bytes\n", header->len);

    printf("Epoch Time: %d:%d seconds\n", header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec);

    for (u_int i = 0; (i < header->caplen); i++)
    {
        if ((i % 16) == 0) printf("\n");
        printf("%.2x ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
}
```

but in the end, I have an error ((LNK1104 cannot open file 'winpcap.lib'))
If anyone can fix this problem I will be thankful.
Or if someone hades another code to implement this data in C++ please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the directory where `wincap.lib` is placed to your library search paths.

Comment: I went to http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm and downloaded the latest version and include the wincap.lib to my library but I faced the same problem

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this) helps.

Comment: 'doxygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
this error happens when I'm trying to build_wdpack from windows batch file provided from  winpcap.org/devel.htm

Comment: Apparently you're expected to have `doxygen` installed in order to generate the documentation. You should lookout for a flag to turn that part off in the build process. Nothing to do with your original question BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library name is not `winpcap.lib`, it is `wpcap.lib`. You probably also need to link against `Packet.lib`. You must tell the linker where the files are. The folders are `Lib` for Win32 and `Lib\x64` for 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/wkoroy/pcap_file_generator) sources of library **pcap_file_generator**. 
Example reading:

```
#include "pcap_file_generator.h"
...

PCAPFILE  * pfr = lpcap_open("./pcaplibtestfile.pcap");
  pcap_hdr_t   phdr;
  if( lpcap_read_header( pfr, &phdr ))
  {
    int rese_rec_read = 0 ;
    pcaprec_hdr_and_data_t  p_rec_data;
    do{   
       rese_rec_read = lpcap_read_frame_record( pfr , &p_rec_data);
      //p_rec_data -  contain data of record
    }while(rese_rec_read>0);
```