# c++ - error with DXGI.h when try include d3d11.h

Tags: c++, directx, codeblocks, directx-11

When I try compile code with Code::Block and Visual Studio, i get error in DXGI.h

error: '__in' has not been declared|

error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token|
and so on

Why it's going on and how can i fix that?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
```

Comment: How did you set up your include file search paths for the project?

Comment: Please specify what compiler you're using. Neither Code::Blocks or Visual Studio are compilers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: I added path to DirectX_SDC.include and DirectX_SDC.lib

Answer (score 1):

You can hit a number of issues when mixing the legacy DirectX SDK headers with the Windows 8.0 SDK, Windows 8.1 SDK, or the Windows 10 SDK. The problems are because the legacy DirectX SDK has some older headers that conflict with the new SDKs.

You likely need two fixes:

First, make sure that you add the DirectX SDK include and lib paths at the *end* of the search path rather than the beginning so you get the newer ones listed first.

For x86/Win32 configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86
```

For x64 native configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64
```

Second, explicitly include the dependent header so you don't end up with the older one:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi.h>    // <-- make sure you pick up the Windows SDK version
#include <d3dx11.h>  //     and not from the DXSDK
```

If you let `d3dx11.h` pull in `dxgi.h` then you'll end up with the wrong one!

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), and [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/)

> Two other things to note here about your code. First, there's no reason at all to use DirectX 10 or `d3dx10.h`. Use DirectX 11 only.
>
> Second, D3DX itself is deprecated including D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) for Direct3D 11 open source replacements.