# How to build and Install TAGLIB in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, taglib, id3v2

I am struggling to create a program which embeds song lyrics in *.mp3 files using C++ programming for my ongoing project. After searching, I found a library named "[TAGLIB](http://taglib.org/)" that can process ID3v2.3 standard metadata. 
According to the LIBTAG installation guide, I ran CMAKE and configured liked [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnrhE.png) and [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJmYU.png) and build with mingw

`C:\Desktop\taglib> mingw32-make`
and
`C:\Desktop\taglib> mingw32-make install`

I got this folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\taglib` having contents inside it, including,

```
bin\libtag.dll
bin\libtag_c.dll
bin\libtag_c.dll

include\*.h files

lib\pkgconfig\taglib.pc
lib\pkgconfig\taglib_c.pc
lib\libtag.a
lib\libtag.dll.a
lib\libtag_c.dll.a
```

In Codeblocks, I linked `libtag.a`, `libtag.dll.a` and `libtag_c.dll.a` and configured search directories to `C:\Program Files (x86)\taglib` and did same to the current project. But compiler gives this type of error for]many times

`undefined reference to _imp___ZN6TagLib6StringC1EPKcNS0_4TypeE'|`

when I tried to compile example codes provided with library.

Then I used `GCC` to compile code.  But this time no luck..

`C:\Program Files (x86)\taglib>gcc -o f.exe framelist.cpp -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/lib/" -libta.a -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include/taglib"`

Getting this error:

```
`
framelist.cpp:32:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
 #include C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include/taglib/id3v2tag.h>
          ^
framelist.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
framelist.cpp:59:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class TagLib::ID3v2:
:Tag'
            << id3v2tag->header()->majorVersion()
                       ^
In file included from framelist.cpp:30:0:
C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include/taglib/mpegfile.h:37:27: note: forward dec
laration of 'class TagLib::ID3v2::Tag'
   namespace ID3v2 { class Tag; class FrameFactory; }
                           ^
framelist.cpp:61:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class TagLib::ID3v2:
:Tag'
            << id3v2tag->header()->revisionNumber()
                       ^
In file included from framelist.cpp:30:0:
C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include/taglib/mpegfile.h:37:27: note: forward dec
laration of 'class TagLib::ID3v2::Tag'
   namespace ID3v2 { class Tag; class FrameFactory; }
                           ^
framelist.cpp:63:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class TagLib::ID3v2:
:Tag'
            << id3v2tag->header()->tagSize()
                       ^
In file included from framelist.cpp:30:0:
C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include/taglib/mpegfile.h:37:27: note: forward dec
laration of 'class TagLib::ID3v2::Tag'
   namespace ID3v2 { class Tag; class FrameFactory; }
                           ^
framelist.cpp:67:14: error: 'TagLib::ID3v2::FrameList' has not been declared
       ID3v2::FrameList::ConstIterator it = id3v2tag->frameList().begin();
              ^
framelist.cpp:68:13: error: 'it' was not declared in this scope
       for(; it != id3v2tag->frameList().end(); it++)
             ^
framelist.cpp:68:27: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class TagLib::ID3v2:
:Tag'
       for(; it != id3v2tag->frameList().end(); it++)
                           ^
In file included from framelist.cpp:30:0:
C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include/taglib/mpegfile.h:37:27: note: forward dec
laration of 'class TagLib::ID3v2::Tag'
   namespace ID3v2 { class Tag; class FrameFactory; }
                           ^
`
```

As you can understand, I'm fairly new to adding external library, help me figuring out, How can I properly install "LIBTAG" to start coding in Codeblocks.

Comment: Related, if not even a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this

Comment: Still couldn't figure out

Comment: It looks like you missed some `#includes`, and also some libs to link. It's hard to tell you what exactly goes wrong without a [MCVE].

Comment: Please see this, https://imgur.com/a/yyA88c2
https://imgur.com/a/vjEptvr
Why this happening?

Comment: Because the linker can't resolve these symbols from all what you gave them (libs, correctly mangled symbols, whatever)

Comment: How to fix this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Tell me, how can I link the exported .a file or .lib file...

Comment: After trying the whole night, in Visual Studio, I changed every possible project setting as like as EXAMPLE projects. After that it's working.....Thanks buddy