# How can I install and use C++ libraries on eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to use [libosmium](https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium) library. Could someone please tell me how do I set up this library after I download it?

All I need to know is the standard way of installing external libraries. I can't really find very clear instructions online.

I'm coding with C++ using the eclipse IDE version 4.18.0.

Comment: What platform are you working on? That makes a big difference.

Comment: Assuming GCC or similar, from the main menu Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->XXX Linker->Libraries , where XXX is the name of the dev tool doing the actual linking. Add the library to the top (Libraries) box and the path to the library to the bottom (Library search path) box. Note: When adding the library leave out the lib prefix and the .a suffix.

Comment: Otherwise Project->Properties->C/C++ General-> Paths and Symbols. Select the Libraries tab and add the library then select the Library Paths tab and add the path to the library.

Comment: Probably need to set the include path for the library as well.

Comment: Are you looking for advice on a) building the library, b) installing the library on your O/S, c) telling Eclipse where you have installed the library or d) all of the above?

Answer (score 1):

For includes: right click on your project and go to Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Compiler >> Includes

you must add the include path for the external library (where the header reside). This information is needed by the Eclipse indexer (code completion etc.) and the compiler

For libraries: right click on your project and go to Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Linker >> Libraries you must add the library search path (option -L) and the library you want to link against (option -l). This info is needed for the linker.

Source: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_external_library_to_my_C.2B.2B_project.3F

**Eclipse-CDT Setting Pictures**

[Include path settings:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofFz9.png)

[Library & library search path settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/305Hy.png)

You can also use `pkg-config` plug in
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt

Here is a link to a similar question with answers: [Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this)

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the other answer, you can usually add a library by looking at the project properties:

- Properties>>C/C++ Build>>Settings>>GCC C++ Compiler>>Includes

However if you're using a makefile project, the Makefile itself must know about the location of libraries.  In this case, in order to avoid an "Unresolved inclusion" warning in the header, you may also want to tell eclipse where the header files are.  This way the autocomplete & "Open Declaration" will work.  This is found in:

- Properties>>C++ General>>Preprocessor Includes Paths, Macros etc.

In my case I couldn't figure out how to add a custom configuration and updated the default configuration.  I added a path for the Android NDK under the GNU C++ -> CTD User Setting Entries